# Animation side changes on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have two simple animations: two images sliding from left to right (first one), and right to left (second one).

```
$('#from_left').animate({opacity: 1.0, left: '30%'}, 2000);
$('#from_right').animate({opacity: 1.0, right: '30%'}, 2000);
```

On Firefox they both comes from the left. Why?

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9se799oh/

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9se799oh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `right: 0%;` to the `#from_right`'s css and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/9se799oh/1/

Comment: Both `left` and `right` properties have an initial value of `auto`. So they basically just go to `top: 0` and `left: 0` (or `right: 0` if `direction` is `rtl`).
So by setting `right: 0` we force it to the right and when we animate, it starts from its initial value we just set.